# How do I convert python(3) list to AWS API format?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like

`users = ["a1234", "b1234", "a2367"]`

and a function to build the data to send in a python request like

```
def patch_group(id, members):
    payload = {
                "Operations":[
                  {
                     "op":"add",
                     "path":"members",
                     "value":[
                        {
                            
                        }
                     ]
                  }
                ]
              }
    payload['Operations'][0]['value'] = members
    return payload
```

im calling the function with `patch_group(1,users)`

The format I need, taken from AWS docs, is

```
"Operations":[
      {
         "op":"add",
         "path":"members",
         "value":[
            {
               "value":"a1234"
            },
               "value":"b1234"
            },
               "value":"a2367"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I convert my list into this format?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def patch_group(id, members):
    payload = {
        "Operations": [
            {
                "op": "add",
                "path": "members",
            }
        ]
    }
    payload['Operations'][0]['value'] = [{"value": member} for member in members]
    return payload

payload = patch_group(None, users)
```

Basically you can just iterate over your list and create the needed dictionary for each list element. Then add it to your payload. Not sure what the `id` is doing in the signature though ;)

Comment: You're an amazing person, thank you.